# Convergence in distribution (exp to degenerate)

Tags: probability, probability-theory

i have some trouble with the following problem.
I seek for a solution and justification if my approach does work (seems too easy, and thats often false :(

let $\lambda_n$ be a sequence of positive numbers. Let $X_1, X_2, ...$ be RV's
s.t. $X_n$ has exp distrib with para $\lambda_n$, therefore $X_n$ has density
$$f_n(x) = \lambda_n e^{-\lambda_n x}, x\geq 0$$
Does $$X_n \to X\equiv 0 \text{  in distribution as  } n\to\infty $$ in the cases
$$\lambda_n \to\infty \text{  as  }n\to\infty$$
$$\lambda_n \to 0 \text{  as  } n\to\infty$$

My first thought was to show that the random variables converge in probability. This could be shown if they converge in $L^1$. Because the first moment of the exp distrib is zero, I get convergence in $L^1$ -> conv in prob -> conv in law. But this is independ of the sequence $\lambda$ and seems too easy. Do I have a mistake in this implications, and if so, what is a solution for this problem ? (Maybe via characteristic fcts...?)

Comment: What does "the first moment of the exp distrib is zero" mean here?  I thought $E[X_n] = 1/\lambda_n$ in your case.

Comment: Yes you are right, I confuse something. thx! Then, Nevertheless, in the first case ($\lambda_n \to \infty) the implication from above should hold. Am I right? But how can I show the second case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you stated, if $\lambda_n\to\infty$, your random variables converge to $0$
in expectation, and hence, by the Markov inequality, in probability.  Also, their distributions converge weak* to the unit point mass at $0$.

If, however, $\lambda_n\to0$ your random variables converge "to $\infty$" in some sense.  If you compactify the nonnegative reals $[0,\infty)$ by adjoining the value $+\infty$, then your $X_n$ converge in distribution to the unit point mass at $\infty$.  If you don't want to do this, you can still conclude that for each $\epsilon>0$, there is a $K$ such that $P(X_n<K)<\epsilon$ for all $n$ sufficiently large.

In the $\lambda_n\to0$ case, the $X_n$ do *not* converge to $0$, as may be seen by calculating $$P(X_n<1)=\int_0^1 \lambda_n\exp(-\lambda_n x)dx=1-\exp(-\lambda_n).$$  This tends to $1-1=0$ as $n\to\infty$. But $X_n\xrightarrow{p}0$ would imply  $P(X_n<1)\to1$.

Comment: First case is clear, thx for justification. Second case: your first solution with the point mass at infinity is clear! I would prefer your second solution but I actually don’t get how to disprove the statement via your approach.. could you explain it in more detail? Thx in advance !

Comment: Now I got the contradiction. Thx!!